# INSERT without deriving from CDatabase or CRecordset

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, mfc, odbc

I'm using `CDatabase` and `CRecordset` directly (without deriving from this classes). A `SELECT` statement for example looks like:

```cpp
CDatabase db;
db.OpenEx(_T("DSN=mydatabase"));
CRecordset rs(&db);
rs.Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly, _T("SELECT id, name FROM user"));
while (!rs.IsEOF()) {
    CString name; // Just for demonstration
    rs.GetFieldValue(1, name);
}
```

What is the correct way to make a `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement with this method?

- There is no `CRecordset::SetFieldValue`
- I can build the whole SQL string (including the values) and execute `CDatabase::ExecuteSQL` but I don't like this solution and prefer to bind the paramaters in some way.

Comment: In the end, a derived CRecordSet with bound fields just builds a SQL string and executes it! That is the way a database works, so why don't use it?!

Comment: @dwo: My intention is to write every line of the code myself and do it without the help from _MFC Application Wizard_ and its automatically generated code.

Comment: @dwo: I tried to [add an MFC ODBC Consumer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d83f7hdk(v=vs.100).aspx), but I'm getting the error "MFC classes can only be added to MFC projects". I'm building a static library (File -> New -> Project -> Win32 Console -> Static Library), which seems to be the reason for this error.

Comment: If you don't want to use generated classes, then I think the only way is to build SQL commands and execute them.